# Python - List index out of range csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a dictionary that counts the number of each entry in the 13th to 17th column of a csv file. This is my code so far:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('hashtag.csv', 'r') as inp, open('hashtag3.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = unicodecsv.writer(out, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    stuff = unicodecsv.reader(inp, delimiter=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    my_dict={}

    for row in stuff:
        for i in range (13,18):
            if row[i] in my_dict:
                my_dict[row[i]]+=1
            else:
                my_dict[row[i]]=1
    print my_dict
```

However, it tells me this, when I try to run it.

> row[i] in my_dict:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I tried taking each index on its own to figure out where it went wrong and found out, that it works with row[13], but not with any of the other integers in my range. 
I thought maybe it's because in the other columns, there are some empty cells, but I can't even do an if-request in those other columns without getting the same error.

Comment: Just to clarify: if it's a CSV file, is your delimiter definitely ```;```?

Comment: Include a small sample of your data. A few rows from the in-file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, for some reason, `row` does not have all 13-18 columns.
Modify the `for` loop to

```
for i in range(13,min(len(row),18)):
```

PS,
Instead of the (somewhat) cumbersome `if row[i] in my_dict` you might consider using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(int)  # accessing a new key returns zero
# ...
for row in stuff:
    for i in xrange(13, min(18, len(row))):
        my_dict[row[i]] += 1
```

Comment: An alternative to `collections.defaultdict` would be `my_dict[row[i]] = my_dict.get(row[i], 0) + 1`.

Comment: @zwer indeed, but I think `defaultdict` code is more "readable" and "elegant" (qualities that are very subjective). Honestly, I use both methods without any preference...

Comment: I get lazy and use @zwer's solution instead of using `defaultdict`.  In my defense, sometimes you do want to fail to access undefined key values.

Comment: @Shai - agreed, but that's a matter of preference - some may argue that it's more elegant when your code doesn't depend on externally defined types, for example (although I wouldn't call `defaultdict` externally defined type, but...) The one advantage it does provide is that you can conditionally set the default value if the key doesn't exist - say you have a lookup table with starting 'counts' mapped by a key, you can use `my_dict[row[i]] = my_dict.get(row[i], lookup[row[i]]) + 1` instead (but then, you can pre-build your keys from that lookup, and... now I'm just rambling...)